# Bootloader Has Disappeared After Reinstalling Windows And Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I was having trouble with my Windows 7 and could not access the router so I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to see if I could network on that, and I could.

After much ado I decided that the best course of action would be to reinstall Windows 7, but I lost the option of booting onto Ubuntu. The thing is, I really liked Ubuntu and wanted to keep using it alongside Windows. I decided to just reinstall Ubuntu from the CD, thus losing all the wee extras I had added.

Lo and behold the PC still boots straight into Windows 7 with no option to go into Ubuntu, what can I do ?

Comment: Please refer http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows , also a possible Duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may have installed using WUBI, the windows installer, in uninstalling windows It also uninstalled your ubuntu install, Since you reinstalled Ubuntu, try using boot-repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks I will try it, download speed bad now so may be tomorrow.

Comment: If you want you can try the second option on the list using the live-cd, so you don't need to download an entire disk